# Fan is not detected

Tags: drivers, nvidia, overheating, fan, temperature

I'm trying to use ubuntu in my laptop. But the fan seems to not working.. I try use sudo pwmconfig but this is the result..

```
sudo pwmconfig
# pwmconfig revision 6166 (2013-05-01)
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no fan-capable sensor modules installed
```

I also try ~$ lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D', the result is this

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1477
    Kernel driver in use: i915
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108M [GeForce GT 635M] (rev a1)     Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 1477
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

My laptop's temperature is really high, what can I do to fix this?

Comment: There probably is no fan speed sensor. That's OK. What grapphics adapted do you have? Which driver is used? Anyway the sensor won't help.

Comment: You have dual graphics. That is why it overheats.  Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command. PLEASE DO NOT POST IT TO COMMENTS!!!!

Comment: Is there anything i can do to cool down my laptop?

Comment: You need to install drivers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two graphics adapters in your system. Now both of them are enabled and consume power.

Also the `nouveau` driver is not good in terms of power.

You need to install proprietary drivers. Run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
```

and reboot.

You can save more power and make the computer cooler if you switch to the integrated adapter by

```
sudo prime-select intel
```

or [using GUI](https://askubuntu.com/a/661924/167850).