# Switch between Intel & nVidia cards ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 16.04, intel

I just bought a new laptop with both an Intel HD 5500 and nVidia GeForce 920M, and I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. According to Google, all I have to do is install the proprietary drivers and choose between cards in the Additional Drivers tab in the Control Panel. As you can see in the attached file, that's what I have done, but nothing seems to happen. Not logging out and back in, not rebooting the laptop. What am I doing wrong?

[Additional Drivers Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tou2d.jpg)

`lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
 Kernel driver in use: i915 

04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce 920M] (rev a1)
 Subsystem: Lenovo GK208M [GeForce 920M]
 Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_361
```

Comment: It is not clear what is the problem. You installed drivers. You can switch the adapters in Nvidia X Server Settings.

Comment: I do, but the change does not happen, though. The Intel Graphics are still running, according to the system.

Comment: Where do you see that  "Intel Graphics are still running"? Anyway they should be running. Dual graphics do not disable Intel completely when you switch to Nvidia.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/661924/167850

Comment: When I run "lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'" How can I know I'm using one or the other?

Comment: Run `prime-select query` and you will see.

Comment: And you do not switch adapters in Additional Drivers Tab. You install or remove drivers there. You look into a wrong place.

Comment: It says "unknown".

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'` terminal command.

Comment: # lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
 Kernel driver in use: i915
--
04:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce 920M] (rev a1)
 Subsystem: Lenovo GK208M [GeForce 920M]
 Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_361

Comment: I asked to [edit] your question and add the output there! The problem must be with SecureBoot. Disable it in BIOS.

Comment: Yep! That was it. Thanks so much Pilot6.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in Ubuntu 16.04 with UEFI and SecureBoot enabled unsigned kernel modules do not load.

In your case `nvidia` module is not loaded. The module is not signed. That should be fixed as a bug.

Disable SecureBoot and the problem should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Find the nvidia management app.
Type nvidia in the dash to find it.
There you can choose which profile you want to be applied, weather

- performance mode (nvidia drivers will used)
- eco mode (intel drivers will be used)

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution that might work for you it's a bash script which switches between nvidia and intel video cards.
Here's the link: https://github.com/bauca/graphics-switcher