# Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't seem to see my gtx 1060 gpu

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia, graphics

Hi :) I've recently bought a new PC with Palit GeForce GTX 1060 6GB Dual video card. Unfortunately, it seems like Ubuntu has some problems with it. When I type "sudo lshw -C display", I get this message:

> ```
>  *-display UNCLAIMED
>    description: VGA compatible controller
>    product: NVIDIA Corporation
>    vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
>    physical id: 0
>    bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
>    version: a1
>    width: 64 bits
>    clock: 33MHz
>    capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
>    configuration: latency=0
>    resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
>
>   *-display
>    description: VGA compatible controller
>    product: Sky Lake Integrated Graphics
>    vendor: Intel Corporation
>    physical id: 2
>    bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
>    version: 06
>    width: 64 bits
>    clock: 33MHz
>    capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
>    configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
>    resources: irq:124 memory:f5000000-f5ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
> ```

and when I go to "Additional drivers", I get this:
[Unknown: Unknown. The device is using an alternative driver.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rl7j8.png)

Comment: You probably need the ppa for very newest drivers. http://askubuntu.com/questions/813676/installing-ubuntu-mate-with-dual-boot-option-on-windows-10-usb-booting-not-hap/814413#814413

Comment: And how do I get this ppa? I've written:
`ubuntu-drivers devices  ...
ubuntu-drivers devices | grep recommended ...
sudo apt-get remove --purge nvidia-* ...
sudo ubuntu-drivers devices ...
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall ...
ubuntu-drivers devices ...
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa ...
ubuntu-drivers devices`

just as they said in the post You linked to, but that didn't change anything (by anything, I mean I still get the same messages as I described in the question).

Sorry, I'm a linux newbie.

Comment: In "Software & Updates", I've change "Download from:" from "Poland server" to "Main server" and something new appeared: https://s17.postimg.org/a0ycqs4e5/Screenshot_from_2016_10_12_23_51_05.png

still, VGA compatible controller appears as UNCLAIMED

Comment: But this is super old. Ubuntu 10 and gtx 560? I would think something could change for the last 5 years. I'll try to follow the answers anyway

Comment: I tried following [these instructions](http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers/680826#680826).

I used `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`  and
`sudo apt-get install nvidia-367`

...and now nothing works. System boots normally, but when the login screen shoul appear, everything goes black and monitor goes into sleep mode... I've discovered that using ctrl+alt+f1 brings up terminal, but that's all. I think that nothing graphics-related works...

Comment: I managed to restore graphics by removing installed nvidia drivers. Now I'm at the beginning again...

Comment: Have you ran `sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Comment: yes; that didn't change anything. I have downloaded [heaven benchmark](https://unigine.com/products/benchmarks/heaven/) and on high settings I get full 5 fps. Nvidia still shows as unclaimed and the driver is ["using X.org X server..."](https://s17.postimg.org/a0ycqs4e5/Screenshot_from_2016_10_12_23_51_05.png)

Comment: Others have just connected to Intel video on motherboard to boot and then installed nVidia driver as above. Then reconnected to nVidia card and had it worked.

Comment: nvidia-370 should support that card. It supports my 1080.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot and install the driver (367 or 370) they both should work.

Comment: @Pilot6 could you tell me, step by step, how I should do that? I  think I managed to install 367 and 370 before, and all it did was to delete all graphics on my pc, but I didn't do it with secure boot disabled, so maybe that will help.

Comment: See the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Disable Secure Boot in BIOS. With Secure Boot enabled proprietary drivers will never load. Then run in a terminal

```
sudo apt purge 'nvidia.*'
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-367 nvidia-prime
```

The 367 driver is a recommended by Nvidia LTS driver.

Comment: What does nvidia-prime do? I heard it's for laptops?

Comment: also - could You please tell me how to disable secure boot? In bios, there is a section where it says "Secure boot - enabled", but it's grayed out, so I cannot change it.

Comment: it looks very much like [this](https://www.all4os.com/content/uploads/2015/07/uefi-secure-boot.png)

Comment: ok, I somehow managed to disable secure boot (deleted all "keys" under the "Secure boot" option). I installed the drivers and what happened is what have happened each time before - after turning on the PC, it goes completely black, monitor goes into the sleep mode and the only thing I can do is enter the terminal by ctrl+alt+f1. Everything goes back to normal after I `purge 'nvidia.*`

Comment: Deleting keys is wrong. You need to disable Secure Boot option.

Comment: If you can't disable in BIOS, use mokutil.

Comment: I did finally manage to disable it . But still, the installation of the drivers led to the same thing that every other time - black screen, no graphics, only ctrl+alt+f1 working.

Comment: No ideas then. I am keeping the answer so other people can see what you already tried.

Comment: I think nvidia-prime is a tool that lets you switch between installed GPUs. Not specific to laptops that I can tell. Source: http://askubuntu.com/questions/661922/how-am-i-supposed-to-use-nvidia-prime

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with the GTX 1060 and 16.04. I followed all of the instructions here and in other threads but couldn't get past the login screen.

I was able to get it working by installing ubuntu 14.04, having secure boot disabled (I don't know if this matters I had just already tried it and kept it that way just in case - I may follow up if I try again with it on), and installing the proprietary drivers.

To install the proprietary drivers these are the exact steps I took. We have similar models so it might work for you.

**CTRL+ALT+F1 #if you haven't already**

```
sudo service lightdm stop 
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/367.57/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.57.run
sudo chmod +x NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.57.run
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-367.57.run
sudo reboot
```

The driver install was done after a completely fresh install of ubuntu 14.04.5.

Here are some of my parts just in case it helps.

- ASUS Z170-A LGA 1151 Intel Z170 HDMI SATA 6Gb/s USB 3.1 USB 3.0 ATX Intel Motherboard
- Intel Core i7-6700K 8M Skylake Quad-Core 4.0 GHz LGA 1151 91W BX80662I76700K Desktop Processor Intel HD Graphics 530
- SAMSUNG 850 EVO 2.5" 500GB SATA III 3-D Vertical Internal Solid State Drive (SSD) MZ-75E500B/AM
- MSI GAMING GeForce GTX 1060 6GB GDDR5 DirectX 12 VR Ready (GeForce GTX 1060 GAMING X 6G)

Comment: This is a bad solution because you will get a black screen after the first kernel upgrade.

Answer (score -1):

The default drivers installed for the graphics card in Ubuntu is `nouveau`. This works fine for most of the times but at certain stages it is just not enough.
On the other hand ppa's can be an alternative solution but in the long run it may cause minor damages to hardware.

**Solution**

1) Download the official drivers from the Nvidia website.

2)Run the installer script as root user

`sudo sh "driver name".run`

3) Reboot the system