# Black screen when installing / dual booting Ubuntu on Win 10 Laptop

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, multiple-monitors

Trying to dual boot Ubuntu Gnome 16.04.3 over Windows 10 (most recent update) via USB drive - using Rufus. Whenever I push enter on the 'Try Ubuntu' or 'Install Ubuntu' options, I just get a blank (back-lit) screen. System information: [Eluktronics P650HP6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01NBUH1HO), i7-7700HQ, nVidia GTX 1060.

I'm pretty sure I've checked most of the basics - Fast Boot disabled, Secure Boot disabled, etc.

I've also tried various combinations of [nomodeset](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/kernel_mode_setting) (see last section for the three commands I used). Also tried setting the forcing the video mode manually using 'video=eDP-1-1' with and without the three nomodeset commands.

I got the eDP-1-1 name during a recent previous install of Ubuntu. I've tried googling a decent amount, but most guides point to resolving nVidia driver issues post installation, rather than during the installation process.

Is my best bet to install Ubuntu through BIOS then use Boot Repair to convert Ubuntu to UEFI mode after? I was reading online elsewhere this isn't such a great idea?

Also what's strange is that I can install Ubuntu on my laptop if I hook up an external monitor (via HDMI), but the installation process occurs on the external display and the machine thinks that external monitor is my primary monitor. The laptop monitor generally works afterwards, but I can't boot Ubuntu afterwards without the external monitor since the login screen appears on the external monitor.

I'm also open to other distros, flavours, etc if that would make the installation process go more smoothly. Was looking into Fedora and OpenSuse a bit, but I just want something stable that runs well so I figured I'd stick to Ubuntu for now. Also I don't intend to do much gaming if any on this OS, just want the thing to run and be able to do some coding.

Comment: Some that have had major issues where nomodeset does not work, have turned off nVidia in UEFI and installed using Intel video. Then add ppa and newest nVidia driver in install and turn nVidia back on.

Comment: Yep, thanks a ton, that seems to have done the trick. For future reference what I did was changed the preferred graphics processor to 'Intel' in nVidia control center, disabled the nVidia drivers in device manager, then disabled all nVidia settings in BIOS.

Comment: I have the same laptop, a Clevo P650HP6-G, it has almost the same problems as you describe. The difference is, that if I install the nvidia-375 (same with nvidia-384 from ppa) package after installation I do get the laptop screen working. But it still only works when I boot with an external monitor attached via HDMI. Additionally after logging in the laptop monitor's resolution becomes very low, only going to decent after _detaching_ the external monitor from HDMI. I had to disable UEFI booting in the BIOS to get things working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is information on the nVidia GTX 1060 on the following pages, the first link being rather complete and the second one related to the card mentioned above:
[How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers)
[Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't seem to see my gtx 1060 gpu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/836239/ubuntu-16-04-doesnt-seem-to-see-my-gtx-1060-gpu)
Mainly get the ppa drivers

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa   
sudo apt-get update   
sudo apt-get upgrade 
sudo apt-get install nvidia-[correct-driver-name-or-number-here]
```

Comment: My issue is I can't even correctly install Ubuntu in the first place, sorry if that wasn't clear. Unless there's a way to enter sudo commands through Grub2? That's as far as I can get right now.