# Problem with nVidia GTX 1060 drivers on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I am facing problem configuring and working with Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 14.04.

At the beginning of my installation, I faced a problem with screen resolution.

I solved this issue by installing manually newer version of linux kernel.

My specs are:

1. Ubuntu 14.04 trusty 4.10.0-35-generic 64bit (en_US.UTF-8, XFCE xubuntu)
2. Intel Core i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz ‖ RAM 15998 MiB ‖ ASUS GL502VMZ
3. nVidia Device [10de:1c20] {nouveau}

I want to work with the nvidia drivers not nouveau. 
I follow the instructions from this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/836239/ubuntu-16-04-doesnt-seem-to-see-my-gtx-1060-gpu) answer and now I see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxntt.png) on the additional driver menu.

The thing is that the command `nvidia-detector` returns `none`.

Also the command `sudo lshw -C display` returns:

```
*-display UNCLAIMED     
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ee000000-eeffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff memory:e0000000-e1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

From this, I understand that something is not configured well, right?