# NVIDIA graphic card

Tags: nvidia, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime, additional-drivers

I have a laptop with **GeForce 820M** and the **Intel HD**.
but i never can make the nvidia turn on, i think, Sorry im new in ubuntu. Help me please i try to install the drivers `sudo apt-get install nvidia-361`.
I read in some other posts that i must have in the nvidia config an option called: PRIME or something like that but i never get it.
I also try to get the drivers in aditional drivers but never see the GeForce or something like that.
I have installed the drivers but in config i only get this:
[Nvidia X settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQSsj.png)
One more Thing how can i know, if the graphic card is with the right driver, or if its working. 
PD: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Did you try going to "Additional Drivers" and selecting your the proprietary drivers for your GPU? Are you sure Ubuntu isn't using your graphics card? Install inxi with "sudo apt-get install inxi", and then run "inxi -G" from terminal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing NVIDIA GEFORCE 820M Driver in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/777884/installing-nvidia-geforce-820m-driver-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

Comment: @PatrickNegus I get this result:`Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
           Card-2: NVIDIA GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M]
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.3 drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) FAILED: nouveau
           Resolution: 1366x768@59.97hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 11.2.0`
@sinclair: i have seen that post too i have tried it

Comment: Check out this http://askubuntu.com/questions/661922/how-am-i-supposed-to-use-nvidia-prime

Comment: @nobody i have try to use the -prime driver it only makes that i cant use the computer, i have to reinstall the ubuntu, the screen goes black all time