# Minecraft Flickering on Lenovo Y700

Tags: graphics, minecraft

I am running a minecraft modpack (FTB), but when I am playing, the game keeps on flickering.

I have 2 graphics cards: a Nvidia Geforce GTX 960M, but running `lspci | grep VGA` returns

> Intel Corporation Skylake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)

Am I running it on the wrong driver/card? or is it that the drivers are not updated properly?

Comment: Did you install the nvidia drivers and prime? See: http://askubuntu.com/a/661924/9543 Make sure to install the correct version for your GPU.

Comment: when opening Nvidea Xserver Settings i dont get the prime tab, nor can i select a driver or gpu.

Comment: Did you install the Nvidia drivers from additional drivers in Ubuntu?

Comment: yes but then minecraft wont launch properly