# System Freezes when logging in after chosing Intel iGPU in NVIDIA settings

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 16.10, nvidia-optimus

Im on an early 2016 Razer Blade (i7-6700HQ, GTX 970M, NVME Storage) On 16.10

I installed the proprietary NVIDIA Drivers and The NVIDIA-Settings as seen in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661922/how-am-i-supposed-to-use-nvidia-prime) post however every time I switch to Intel, log out and try to log back in the whole sytem freezes up. I was only able to fix it by removing the NVIDIA Driver and NVIDIA-Settings. How would I go about fixing this and is there a way to switch between the two without having to log out and log back in?

Answer (score 0):

I am on similar hardware (ASUS UX501vw) and am having the same issue, but am currently using a workaround.

Workaround:
When you boot up make sure your laptop is not plugged into power. Somehow the driver is not booting properly when on power. When your all booted up AND logged in to your 16.10 plug back in the power and proceed as if nothing had happened... :D.