# Messed up Nvidia drivers and can't fix it

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, lubuntu, xorg

```
Operational system: Lubuntu 18.04 // upgraded forcefully from 16.04
    architeture: amd64 
    Video graphic card: GeForce 7200 GS / 7300 SE
```

Everything was functioning normally, but sometimes when i was watching videos on the YOuTube [in G. Chromer] the screen froze with only the sound of the video continuing and even trying to turn on/off Num/Caps Lock keys didn't nothing, so i had to restart the computer when this happened. I figured that the problem may be the drivers, so i thought that i should reinstall the drivers. I purged the nvidia drivers, and tried reinstalling it, and it messed everything. Now my screen is widescreen and stretched and the image is bad. i tried reinstalling again the drivers [both by apt-get install and aptitude install] but nothing really happens after installing the drivers.

I can't open the Nvidia X Server Settings [it is in the menu, if i click on it nothing happens]. Some commands i used and their outputs:

```
nvidia-settings

 ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
```

.

```
$ lsmod | grep nvidia
$: command not found
```

.

```
$ sudo lshw -c display
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: G72 [GeForce 7200 GS / 7300 SE]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:fa000000-faffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:c0000-dffff
```

What should I do? I looked for many solutions in this site, but none of them worked for me.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I tried Terrance's link steps, and what i'm getting:

```
$ nvidia-settings

ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded


ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system


$ nvidia-smi

Command 'nvidia-smi' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install nvidia-340      
sudo apt install nvidia-utils-390
```

I still can't open the NVidia Server X Settings, nor can't i change things like screen size. Oh, and the latest driver that supports my graphic card is the 304, so i think that installing these drivers that doesn't support my graphic card may mess everything up more. The command "lsmod | grep nvidia" returns no output.

edit²: tried

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-304
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  lib32gcc1 libc6-i386
Recommended packages:
  libcuda1-304 nvidia-opencl-icd-304
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  libgl1-mesa-glx libglx-mesa0
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  lib32gcc1 libc6-i386 nvidia-304
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 2 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/38,5 MB of archives.
After this operation, 188 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 171909 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (18.0.0~rc5-1ubuntu1) ...
Removing libglx-mesa0:amd64 (18.0.0~rc5-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libc6-i386.
(Reading database ... 171896 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6-i386_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6-i386 (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package lib32gcc1.
Preparing to unpack .../lib32gcc1_1%3a8-20180414-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking lib32gcc1 (1:8-20180414-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package nvidia-304.
Preparing to unpack .../nvidia-304_304.137-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nvidia-304 (304.137-0ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libc6-i386 (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2) ...
Setting up lib32gcc1 (1:8-20180414-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up nvidia-304 (304.137-0ubuntu2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-304/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf (x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/nvidia-304/alt_ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf (i386-linux-gnu_gl_conf) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/share/nvidia-304/glamor.conf to provide /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/glamoregl.conf (glamor_conf) in auto mode
dpkg: error: version '-' has bad syntax: revision number is empty
dpkg: error: version '-' has bad syntax: revision number is empty
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia-304
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
Loading new nvidia-304-304.137 DKMS files...
Building for 4.15.0-20-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 4.15.0-20-generic
ERROR: Cannot create report: [Errno 17] File exists: '/var/crash/nvidia-304.0.crash'
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.15.0-20-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/nvidia-304/304.137/build/make.log for more information.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.130ubuntu3) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-20-generic
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/i386-linux-gnu_GL.conf: No such file or directory
/sbin/ldconfig.real: Warning: ignoring configuration file that cannot be opened: /etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf: No such file or directory

$ nvidia-smi
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with NVIDIA driver. Make sure that latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried?  It can make it harder for us to help you when you leave such a broad range of solutions that might have helped.  Have you tried https://askubuntu.com/a/1030901/231142 ?  The NVIDIA driver installation is in the bottom half of the answer.  If you want the CUDA toolkit as well, that is in the top half.

Comment: Tried things like reinstalling X, installing other Nvidia drivers, purging them again, installing all needed dependencies from anything i tried... oh... i tried to follow the steps on the link you provided, but it didn't help at all. 

I still can't open the NVidia X Server Settings. I'm unable to do simple things like resizing my screen... i could do that before messing up eveything.

Comment: Yep, I just looked it up and confirmed that it is the 304 driver.  Unfortunately the `nvidia-smi` is not going to work with that driver as it is not available in that package.  Did `lsmod | grep nvidia` find the driver installed?  And are you still having an issue with launching `nvidia-settings`?  I am sorry about the link above, I didn't think about older cards not working with the newer drivers.

Answer (score 1):

sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx

Comment: I did that command, i installed everything, but... still... I can't open the Nvidia settings, and i can't do things like resizing my screen.

Answer (score 1):

nvidia-304 driver has been removed from 18.04 because it run out of support and Kernel 4.15 doesn't compile it.
Here is a patch, but I haven't tested it 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304/+bug/1737750

Nouveau is the option that ubuntu gives but i might have some problem, for example Kodi doesn't support nouveau.
more info:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-304/+bug/1748000

https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1032541/linux/304-137-doesn-t-install-in-ubuntu-18-04-got-removed-from-ubuntu-repositories-/

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem with:

```
sudo apt install libwayland-egl1 
sudo dpkg -a --configure
reboot
```

Seems to be some kind of issue with the 2 files libwayland-egl1 and the one which installs libwayland-egl1-mesa. Have noticed that with the libwayland-egl1-mesa installed lots of problems items won't open etc. Perhaps this is an upgrade issue since I have only come across this in upgrade situations so far.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding:

```
slab_common.usercopy_fallback=y
```

to kernel options. It worked for me, no more frozen black screens.
I am using the NVidia driver 304-137 with a 4.17.0 kernel.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo prime-select nvidia
```

logout and re login, `nvidia-settings` will can open the nvidia-gui

Comment: If you're like me and don't know what `prime-select` is, take a look at this question that asks [how am I supposed to use nvidia-prime?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661922/how-am-i-supposed-to-use-nvidia-prime). Also note that this does not appear to be available on Debian. Just Ubuntu.