# How to install NVIDIA GTX 950M driver in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, desktop-environments

Im using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and GTX 950m
I'm already installing GTX 950m driver, but when I check with `lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'`, I see:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 
(rev 06)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. HD Graphics 530
Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M] 
(rev a2)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GM107M [GeForce GTX 950M]
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

I can see `Kernel driver in use: i915`, I want to change `i915` to `nvidia`, because I think my Ubuntu use Intel Graphics (i915) although I was installed NVIDIA driver

UPDATE 1: 
  I accessed a link, and I see my Ubuntu use NVIDIA. But I have 2 boots: Window 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. When I use Ubuntu I feel colors were not rights (it's mean colors between Ubuntu 18.04 and Window 10 it not same, color of Window 10 better than Ubuntu 18.04), and when I play a website game in Ubuntu, very lag ( my internet is good, it's no problem), so I think my VGU (FPS) very low, and to use NVIDIA play the web game, does it happen?

Comment: That looks right: i915 is used for Intel GPU, and nvidia for Nvidia GPU. Not sure what else you want to happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How am I supposed to use nvidia-prime?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661922/how-am-i-supposed-to-use-nvidia-prime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks liek you have hybrid graphics in your laptop.
There are two video adapters Intel and Nvidia.
The i915 driver is for Intel.

When you run in terminal

```
lspci -knn | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D'
```

you see **both** adapters (intel and nvidia).

Now follow this tutorial to pick which one you want to use
https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-card-ubuntu

Comment: I will access a link, and I see my Ubuntu use NVIDIA. But I have 2 boots: Window 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. When I use Ubuntu I feel colors were not rights (it's mean colors between Ubuntu 18.04 and Window 10 it not same, color of Window 10 better than Ubuntu 18.04), and when I play a website game in Ubuntu, very lag ( my internet is good, it's no problem), so I think my VGU (FPS) very low, and to use NVIDIA play the web game, does it happen?