# Ubuntu 19.04 quite hot temperature with low usage

Tags: cpu, temperature

I noticed that a zone of my laptop is quite hot even with low usage, for example, reading a PDF file and the fans are on. Doing the same action with Windows 10 (I have a dual boot) this doesn't happens, the zone is cool.

Why does this happen? Is it due to high CPU usage? Or what?

Is it possible to fix this problem?

Edit 1

Resut of command

```
lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company UHD Graphics 620 (Whiskey Lake)
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel modules: i915

02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] (rev a1)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile]
Kernel driver in use: nvidia
Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

Edit 2

```
prime-select query

nvidia
```

Edit 3

I tried to select the use of Intel integrated GPU without results.

With Ubuntu 19.04 thermald is already installed and PC is quite hot, not cool like in Windows. 
I also noticed the battary goes down very slowly. I don't see this speed decrease on Windows.

Is this a problem of Ubuntu or is it only for Ubuntu 19.04?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Please also add output of `prime-select query` and I am ready to answer.

Comment: Try `tlp`: https://askubuntu.com/questions/391474/stop-cpu-from-overheating

Comment: You can install `laptop-mode-tools` to economy power on battery.

Answer (score 4):

Your computer is hot, because it is always using Nvidia GPU, while Windows uses it in case it is needed for heavy GPU tasks like games.

Ubuntu doesn't switch graphics automatically. You can use `nvidia-prime` or `bumblebee` to switch Nvidia graphics.

See [THIS ANSWER](https://askubuntu.com/a/661924/167850) for more details.

You can also use CLI commands:

```
sudo prime-select intel
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

You can also install `laptop-mode-tools` to economy power.

Comment: Thx. I will try your solution

Comment: You need to log out and log in after you switch graphics.

Comment: thx again. With your solution the temperature of a zone of pc seems a bit lower then before and fans are off, but the problem persists. This zone which is quite hot with Windows it is very cool (and fans are always off)...

Answer (score 2):

I'd install `thermald` to keep your machine cool when using Nvidia video...

- `sudo apt-get update`
- `sudo apt-get install thermald`

`Thermald` comes with a default configuration file at `/etc/thermald/thermal-conf.xml` that will control most computers, but may need to be customized for some computers. See `man thermal-conf.xml` for some details and examples. Once one has modified the configuration file, stop `thermald` and restart it:

```
sudo service thermald restart
```

After installing thermald, I'd stop the `thermald` process, and run it manually as `sudo thermald --no-daemon` to watch its actions in real time. This real time info can be used to create your own customized thermal-conf.xml file. See `man thermald` for more information.

```
sudo service thermald stop
sudo thermald --no-daemon --loglevel=debug
```

You can search for `thermald` here on Ask Ubuntu to see what previous answers there are.

A good starter reference is at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/PowerManagement/ThermalIssues

Comment: I read the Thermald's wiki. As far I understood it monitors CPU temperature with sensors and tweaks the cooling conotrol to cool the system, so it just control the fan? I want to prevent useless usage of CPU and subequent heating (or GPU) for tasks which need few resources (as Windows does I think).

Comment: @Franky17 no, not to control the fan, per se, but the CPU. Just try thermald, and if it doesn't help (after you adjust the conf file, if need be) then just uninstall it :-)

Comment: Yep, I will try it anywhere

Comment: I have Ubuntu 19.04, thermald is already installed... I also noticed that pc battery goes down rapidly.

Comment: @Franky17 if the battery goes down too quickly, it may be due to the use of the Nvidia video. Install `lm-sensors` and check the running temps. You may need to customize the thermald conf file for your computer.