# How to install Intel HD Graphics driver on 20.04?

Tags: drivers, graphics, intel-graphics, 20.04

I have 2 GPUs: Intel HD Graphics 620 and NVIDIA GeForce 930MX
Ubuntu has automatically installed the proprietary driver for the NVIDIA GPU.
But, I can't see the Intel HD Graphics GPU in update manager.
I think that everything on my laptop is using the NVIDIA card, wich is causing it to overheat when I don't have any applications open.

Here is the output of *sudo intel_gpu_top*:

[image: intel_gpu_top]

It seems like Ubuntu is not using the Intel GPU.

Is there a way to install a driver for Intel HD Graphics 620?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Intel Graphics driver's preinstalled in the kernel.

https://www.linuxbabe.com/desktop-linux/switch-intel-nvidia-graphics-card-ubuntu shows `sudo prime-select intel` switches back to Intel and `prime-select query` shows which card is active.

More detail at https://askubuntu.com/a/661924/197910

Comment: Well, I don't see it in software & updates. The intel_gpu_top command says that there is no usage of my Intel GPU. Is it possible to switch between these GPUs? I would like to use the NVIDIA GPU for gaming and Intel for other things.

Comment: Update added above.

Comment: Thank you so much! I forgot that I already had this feature enabled in my previous Ubuntu installation. But, after I reinstalled it, it's gone.

Comment: I have an intel processor. After upgrading from Kubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 everything seemed sluggish. With top I could see that the Xorg and kwin_x11 combined for a total processor usage between 40-50% CPU. After doing prime-select intel, both process account for ~ 1% CPU. Everything is now much more snappy and feels like it used.

This is a very good thing to know!!!