# Ubuntu is not Detecting my Graphics Card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics

I just installed Ubuntu on my computer and I have an Nvidia GTX 1050 Ti series GPU (I forgot which one I have as it is not showing up). I noticed the applications that use the GPU are slow and sometimes freeze. I looked at the system monitor and it wasn't showing that I had a graphics card installed, and the GPU did not show in those applications. If I go into `Settings>About` it shows my built-in Intel HD Graphics 530 which I do not want to use.

I tried to install the additional drivers for Nvidia but my computer just shows a blinking cursor and I had to reinstall Ubuntu.

I am willing to reinstall Ubuntu.

Specs:
Boot method: UEFI
CPU: Intel Core i7-6700 CPU @ 3.40GHz × 8
Memory: 16GB
Graphics cards: Intel HD Graphics 530/Nvidia GTX 1050 Ti

Ubuntu Version: 20.04.1 LTS
OS Type: 64-bit

Comment: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux and sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-440 from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1253773/307670)

Comment: @User24601 This is wrong. Why the 440 old driver?

Comment: @SlimiSlime You need to install Nvidia drivers. Software & Updates -> Additional Drivers.

Comment: @Pilot6 because it worked

Comment: @User24601 Well, it could be long ago, or it could be another Nvidia device ;-)

Comment: Is this a desktop computer with a truly dedicated GPU or a laptop with hybrid graphics?  Please find out which GPU model you have and add it to the question even if that means that you have to do some research or read the documentation

Comment: @Nmath It is a desktop, and my GPU is the GTX 1050 Ti

Comment: So install the drivers `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` or using the GUI.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: Where is the monitor connected? If it is a desktop with a PCI GPU, you need to connect your monitor to the GPU, not to the MB.

Comment: Please post your solution below so that future visitors can apply your solution.  If you found the cause be sure to tell us about that too.  What we do here is host a library of questions and answers about Ubuntu. Your answer may be valuable to others. Please don't keep it to yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution (By Pilot6):

Run the command: `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`

And Reboot