# NVIDIA drivers installed but not available in Additional Drivers

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel, graphics

My system is a Samsung NP450R5E-X04IT Ativ Book 4 with GPU NVIDIA GF117M. It runs Ubuntu 21.10 with Gnome Shell 40.5 and kernel 5.13.0-20 on X11 session.
Last fresh installation was with Ubuntu 20.04, then I updated the system every 6 months with the regular OS updates.

I use Nouveau drivers, no NVIDIA drivers were installed. Now, I want to install them. Firstly, I tried the following:

```
$ sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
No drivers found for installation.
```

Then, I installed them by `sudo apt install nvidia-drivers-470`. The installation is ok (following the output with relevant data):

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-470
Reading package lists... Done
[...]
0 upgraded, 69 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 305 MB of archives.
After this operation, 858 MB of additional disk space will be used.
[...]
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
INFO:Enable nvidia
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/put_your_quirks_here
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/lenovo_thinkpad
DEBUG:Parsing /usr/share/ubuntu-drivers-common/quirks/dell_latitude
Loading new nvidia-470.74 DKMS files...
Building for 5.13.0-20-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Building initial module for 5.13.0-20-generic
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Done.

nvidia.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.13.0-20-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-modeset.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.13.0-20-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-drm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.13.0-20-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-uvm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.13.0-20-generic/updates/dkms/

nvidia-peermem.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.13.0-20-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod..........

DKMS: install completed.
[...]
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.13.0-20-generic
```

However, drivers are not listed in Additional Drivers tab even after a reboot.

[image: Additional Drivers tab]

`lspci` command shows the follwing controllers:

```
 $ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd GeForce 710M
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

I've tried also to uinstall `nvidia-driver-390` according to [NVIDIA driver is not detected in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253127/nvidia-driver-is-not-detected-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts) but to no avail.

What prevents nvidia-drivers from appearing in Additional Drivers tab? Are there some
missing commands to run to make the NVIDIA drivers selectable?

Comment: It looks like there is a problem with the detection of Nvidia cards on the system. Now, installing however many drivers for however many devices will not solve the problem if those devices are not detected. Knowing more info about the system may shed some light on the problem, but as is, all we know is that `lspci` does not have anything Nvidia related.

Comment: @mikewhatever I've done a small update about my computer and its history. About your observations: `inxi` recognizes the NVIDIA GPU, so it's strange the `lspci` does not.

Comment: added further details: `lspci` list my GPU as 3D controller.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1253127/nvidia-driver-is-not-detected-in-ubuntu-20-04-lts  Try an older driver like the 390 -- may require an older kernel.

Comment: Installed `nvidia-driver-390` but no differences: drivers are not available in Additional Drivers.

Comment: Please add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'`. But the driver seems to be properly installed.

Comment: @Pilot6 edited the question.

Comment: The driver is installed and in use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Nvidia driver is installed and in use. You can report a bug saying that driver selection is unavailable in GUI.